# Different CSS for Different Browser Size

Tags: jquery, css, resize, window

I've got a question about windowdependant CSS'es. It's a very common question, but somehow it's not working for me, with Wordpress. Anyway, at the moment I'm using the script adviced by Nettuts. I just want to target different CSS styles when the user resizes his window. I know I need to use $(window).width for that. What I have now is:

```
function checkWindowSize() {

    if ( $(window).width() < 800 ) {
        $('body').addClass('small');
    }
    else {
        $('body').removeClass('small');
    }

}

$(window).resize(checkWindowSize);
```

It certainly does the job. But.. There's a little glitch. When I resize the window, it does target another css-style. But when I leave the window at a smaller size than 800, push F5 (refresh), I need to resize the window manually (for 1 px) before the targeted css takes place. It doesnt automatically target it, just when I resize the screen for a small bit.. I played with the position of the scripts, like putting the new CSS before the actual CSS, but that didn't do so well.

Any ideas? If I'm not clear enough, just tell me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call it once the window loads at the start as well:

```
function checkWindowSize() {

    if ( $(window).width() < 800 ) {
        $('body').addClass('small');
    }
    else {
        $('body').removeClass('small');
    }

}
$(window).load(checkWindowSize);
$(window).resize(checkWindowSize);
```

Comment: Thank you for the compliment.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using media queries?

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/

Comment: Yes, I have. But IE doesnt support that. And my client is oldfashion :p

Comment: @DonMunter IE9+ does support them. And you can polyfill older IE browsers: https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond

Answer (score 3):

You can use **[Adapt.js](http://adapt.960.gs/)** for this. Adapt determines which CSS file to load **depending on the width** and will switch the CSS-file on **resize-event** or triggered by tablet or phone tilt.

Also you can use **Media Queries** with a **[polyfill](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond)** for older browser support instead of Adapt.js.

Answer (score 0):

You're only calling your `checkWindowSize` method when the window resizes. When you refresh the page, no resizing occurs, so you never check the size and never add the class.

So you also need to call `checkWindowSize` when the page loads. Add this, in addition to the code you already have:

```
$(function() { checkWindowSize(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, mediaqueries are the way togo. You've brobably seen HTML like this:

```
<link href='style.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' media='screen'>
```

The W3C introduced [Mediaqueries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) to further specify the media on which stylesheets should be used, this circumvents the disadvantages of browser sniffing, and makes it also work without javascript.

Comment: I do indeed use that for mobile websites. But according to the example of css-tricks (http://css-tricks.com/examples/ResolutionDependantLayout/example-one.php) is doesn't work in IE.

Comment: that's true, older browsers just ignore them.